# What happened to my "project/objects info" footer and how do I get it back?

Tags: interface

I have no idea what I did or hit to get the footer info I usually see (e.g. # tris, edges, vertices, faces per visible project meshes or actively-edited mesh) to disappear. The screenshot was taken from my current project's Object mode; it currently only shows my version number, and this change persisted even after rebooting Blender. How do I get the footer back?

[image]

Comment: By default in 2.9 there'll be only Blender version afaik, as shown on the screenshot. You can enable those for previewing like explained in the linked answer

Comment: Thank you! I learned something with that linked answer. No idea when I unchecked the things in question, but now it's fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the version number and check the options you're interested in.

You can have thoose infos in the 3d window overlays also, checking the "statistics" option.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. (Linked answer has more, I see.)